# Appcelerator can't find Android SDK

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio, appcelerator-cli

Appcelerator was working fine on my Windows 10 PC a few days ago. Today when I try to build my app I get error messages. Suddenly Appcelerator can't find the Android SDK on my machine.

[image]

[image]

I know the SDKs are there, I'm not sure why it can't find them.

I have tried reinstalling Appcelerator Studio, Appcelerator CLI, Node, Java, and the Android SDK's all to no avail.

Comment: Could you run the command with debug & trace level logs to see if that gets you more info on the error? `cmd /C "set DEBUG=* && ti setup check -l trace"` Also run `cmd /C "set DEBUG=* && ti info -t android -l trace"`. Did you change NodeJS versions or install new Android API levels just before it stopped working?

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator I haven't updated the Android API's or Node. Here is a dump of the errors when I run check or info with log level trace [link](http://pastebin.com/am9jJHVK)

Comment: OK, there's something in your environment that our `node_appc` lib is not handling well here: https://github.com/appcelerator/node-appc/blob/master/lib/jdk.js#L230. Could you open `C:\Users\jlaw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\lib\jdk.js` and after line 288 add `console.log(JSON.stringify(jdks))`?

Comment: I think our corporate anti virus may have been causing this problem, I disabled it and appc works again.

Comment: Great! Could you add that as answer and mark is as accepted so that others can see it has been handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into this issue several times, and it appears to be related to my system path pointing at the wrong version of Java. I have both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Java installed. Appcelerator requires the 32 bit. If my path is pointing at the 64 bit version I see this error. Changing the path fixes the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try these steps:

1. Clean your current CLI - delete .appcelerator/install/ 5.2.0-265
2. [sudo] npm install -g appcelerator@4.2.3-2
3. appc use 5.2.0-265

Now run `appc ti info` and look for android sdk.

Comment: I had tried this and unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Install Android SDK from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools) and set the path to the installation location, preferrably `%APPDATA%\android-sdk` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have the SDKs installed. Appcelerator was working fine for me up until yesterday. For some reason Appcelerator doesn't see the SDKs anymore.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the SDK, updating necessary stuff using SDK Manager and setting the path in appcelerator?